# How to find next minimum in a hash map key?

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I have a scenario where I have a map:

```
BiMap <Integer, String> map;
```

and a list which tracks the index which are processed.

```
List<Integer> filled;
```

While processing if the filled list contains the key then I should find the next min key from the map which is already not in the filled list.

Can some one tell me is there an easy way to do this without doing many iterations?

```
for (int i =0 ;i <size; i++) {
    if(map.contiansKey(i)) {
        Integer min = list.contains(i) ? getNextMinFrom(map, filled) : null;
        if min != null ?System.out.println(map.get(min)) : continue;
    }
}
```

For Eg:

```
Filled - 0, 4, 5, 6

Map - (1,dfs) (4,efs) (5,sdfs) 

in the 0 th iteration..  output - dfs (1 is min)
      in 4th iteration ... output shoudl be 4efs (4 is the next min) 
....
```

The issue is I can not remove entries from the list.

Comment: How involved do you want to get? You could introduce another data structure (i.e heap) or do some sorting to help with your runtime.

Comment: I am thinking of add remove all or retainall to map's keyset and do collections.min ???

Comment: I am still a bit confused on your prompt, are you saying that you have to populate the filled array with the map's keys in order?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, filled array is already filled. basically I want to make sure if the map contains key and if it already in the filled array I need to find another key (next min) which is not in the filled list

Comment: Besides the abstruse syntax `if min != null ?System.out.println(map.get(min)) : continue;`, which isn’t even remotely Java, your problem description is inconsistent. You expect your code to print `dfs` when `i==0`, but since `map.containsKey(0)` would return `false`, this would never happen. It’s also unclear why your “issue is I can not remove entries from the list”, when your task description doesn’t involve any removal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a `TreeSet` initialized with the 'KeySet' of your `map` and while you add Any key to `filled` remove it from 'TreeSet',as a result, the first element of `TreeSet` is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achieve? Start from the front of the filled array and go until you find the first value that is in filled but not in the map?

```
public int get smallestUnusedValue() {
    for(int i = 0; i < filled.size(); i++)
        if(!map.containsKey(filled.get(i)))
            return i;
}
```

Comment: Updated my question with eg

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use a `HashMap` specifically?  Implementations of [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html), such as [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), provide methods to look up keys "adjacent to" a given value, without requiring an exact map.  The [`higherEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#higherEntry-K-) method seems to do what you want.